# How to send a custom message as a sms using Twilio with django-two-factor-auth

Tags: django, twilio, django-two-factor-auth

Currently django-two-factor-auth package sends a default message `Your Twilio security code is 1231230` . I would like to customize this text except the 7 digit different/dynamically generated code.

Comment: Where is this message sent? Are you sure it's not sent by Twilio and can not be configured?

Comment: I am unware where this message is sent in django-two-factor-auth. Twilio does have examples where we can send custom messages along with OTP token.

Comment: You will need to determine if the message is sent using Twilio's standard /messages resource or sent via Twilio Verify. If it is Twilio Verify, only the application name can modified (in your case that would be `Twilio`).